# extract data from json with python

Tags: python, json

Bear with me, I'm totally new in python :-) and this my first ever question here.
I've been looking around here and wasn't able to find the answer. I'm sorry in advance if this has been answered already; if so, please point me in the right direction:-)

I've got this json file, named export.json

Here the contents:

```
{"10.0": ["mp-cacao", 32.0, 2.1], "38.0": ["mp-sucre", 36.0, 1.9], "36.0": ["mp-farine", 40.0, 0.5], "37.0": ["mp-lait", 44.0, 3.0], "40.0": ["heures M-O", 48.0, 10.0], "39.0": ["heures machine", 52.0, 0.7]}
```

-The numbers between quotes (10.0, 38.0 etc) are databases ids (this is an extract of an Odoo database (CRM/ERP tool)

-"mp-cacao", "mp-sucre", etc are the name

**-32.0, 36.0 etc are the quantities (that's the field i'm interested on)**

I've been trying to come up with a python code for

1. reading this data
2. most importantly, to be able to extract the first number between the square brackets to be able to send this number back to a database

So far I was able to read the file or some specific entry in the file with the following code

```
import json

with open("export.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print (json_data)
```

or to read a specific entry, example the first one

```
import json

with open("export.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    print (json_data['10.0'])
```

The code above returns this

```
['mp-cacao', 32.0, 2.1]
```

Finally the question: how can I extract and use just the second number in each entry = the quantities?

Comment: http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/native-datatypes.html#lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key, value in json_data.items():
    print(key, value[1])
```

You will get id and the second value in your list. 
Is that what you are going to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to access the second value and had the feeling I could achieve this with a for loop, but had no idea how to. I don't necessarily want to print it; in fact I needed to know just how to access it. Now I will look on how to actually send this info into the Odoo database. Thank you a million!

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark my answer as a solution if you liked it. Thanks and good luck!